# Show that are infinitely many solutions in rational numbers $(x,y)$ for the equation $x^2+7y^2=1.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I think this is to do with the congruence $\mod 4$.

Comment: So rational numbers, not necessarily integers, right?

Comment: Yes, rationals.

Comment: several ways to answer this; what are you doing in class now, and what is the book?

Comment: I can say this much: it has no solutions in integers besides $(1, 0)$. And I suspect it has no solutions besides that in rational numbers.

Comment: Quadratic residues, Pythagorean triples and Pell's equation.

Comment: Alright, so presumably not geometry nor algebraic number theory.

Comment: @Albert: $(-1,0)$ is a different solution, as is $(\frac34,\frac14)$.

Comment: @Henning yes, I forgot about the negative integers.

Answer (score 5):

Let $\left(\dfrac{m}n,\dfrac{k}n\right)$ be a rational solution. We then need
$$m^2+7k^2 = n^2 \implies n^2-m^2 = 7k^2 \implies (n+m)(n-m)=k^2 \cdot 7$$
Choosing $k$ to be odd, we see that
$$n=\dfrac{k^2+7}2 \text{ and }m = \dfrac{k^2-7}2$$
as a pair of solutions, i.e.,
$$(x,y) = \left(\dfrac{k^2-7}{k^2+7}, \dfrac{2k}{k^2+7}\right)$$generates infinitely many solutions for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a rational point at $(-1,0).$ Any line through that point with rational slope (not vertical) will intersect the ellipse in a second point, which will also have rational coordinates.

This is one of the common ways of presenting Pythagorean triples.

Usually, you would call the slope $m/n$ with $\gcd(m,n) = 1,$ also take $n \geq 1.$ The second point on the ellipse will have rational coordinates $(x,y)$ expressed in terms of $(m,n).$

Comment: Another way to see this is to imagine solving for the intersection between the line and the ellipse algebraically. For a rational slope $q$ the equation $x^2+7(q(x+1))^2=1$ reduces to a quadratic equation with rational coefficients; since you know one rational solution $x=-1$ the other one is rational too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes. I am hoping the student will carefully write this out and get specific expressions for $(x,y).$

Comment: x @Will, hm, yes, that's instructive indeed. I didn't know that, actually. Much nicer than mucking about with $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-7})$ ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm, glad you like it. It still works for $Ax^2 + B y^2 = 1$ when integers $A,B > 0$ are both not squares, assuming we can find one rational base point. So, the trick of factoring shown in the other answer would not work then. Also $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 = 1$ with $B^2 - 4AC < 0.$